# Conditional formating based on formula in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have 2 Excel 2007 PT-PT sheets:
One (sheet1) has multiple columns to be validated.
The other (base_valid) has 5 columns to be validated.
I'm trying to validate the "regioes" (M2) column using a macro:

```
Sub Validar_Regioes()
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition, cond3 As FormatCondition
    Set rg = Range("M2", Range("M2").End(xlDown))

    'clear any existing conditional formatting
    rg.FormatConditions.Delete

    'define the rule for each conditional format
    Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlExpression, "=COUNTIF(base_valid!$B$6:$B$10|M2)>0")

    'define the format applied for each conditional format
    With cond1
    .Interior.Color = vbGreen
    .Font.Color = vbWhite
    End With

End Sub
```

The idea is to check if the region in M2 column matches any of the values in the base_valid regions range (base_valid!$B$6:$B$10)
I keep getting "invalid procedure call or argument" message when I call the macro.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"=COUNTIF(base_valid!$B$6:$B$10|M2)>0")` should it not be something like `"=COUNTIF(base_valid!$B$6:$B$10;M2)>0")` You typed `|` instead of `;` (or `,` if you got english version of Excel)

Comment: Tried with , and ; and I get the same message! :(

Comment: What about `Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=COUNTIF(base_valid!$B$6:$B$10;M2)>0")` ? Replace COUNTIF with the name of the function on whatever language you are using Excel

Comment: That way I get "Argument not optional"

Comment: It works perfect for me, what is the language of your excel? Also, what is the separator for arguments in functions in your excel? is it the `;` or the `,`? And make sure the sheet `base_valid` exists and make sure range `base_valid!$B$6:$B$10` is not merged and it does not contains any errors

Comment: Ok, It worked for me because i was adding references to SAME worksheet. In CF rules you cannot add references to ranges from other worksheets! so `base_valid!$B$6:$B$10` it's raising that error. Try it manually and a pop up alert will tell you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be tricky here. Conditional formatting rules don't allow to add references to ranges on other worksheets, not even manually! An alert will pop up!

[image]

The pop up alert says *can't use references to other workbooks or worksheets for criterias in conditional formatting*

But Excel got another function that can help, called INDIRECT

> **[INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)**

This wonderful function will allow us to reference a range in a different worksheet but as it where on same worksheet. To reference a range, use the reference name as string (as text)

So the formula we will be using as criteria is:

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("base_valid!$B$6:$B$10");M2)`

So your VBA code needs to be fixed like this:

```
Dim rg As Range
Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition, cond3 As FormatCondition
Set rg = Range("M2", Range("M2").End(xlDown))

Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(""base_valid!$B$6:$B$10"");M2)")

With cond1
    .Interior.Color = vbGreen
    .Font.Color = vbWhite
End With
```

This worked for me perfectly! After applying macro, I get this:

[image]

oh, my data in `base_valid` worksheet is like this:

[image]

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

**UPDATE DECEMBER 2019:**

Thanks to @BigBen, another option is using a global-scoped named range, instead of indirect. In this case, you can create a name, let's say, `MyValuesList`, which references range `base_valid!$B$6:$B$10`.

Then, the CF rule would be `=COUNTIF(MyValuesList;M2)` and it would work properly.

So if you use a named range, there is no need of using `INDIRECT`.

Your code could be:

```
Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=COUNTIF(MyValuesList;M2)")
```

Comment: I added -> Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=CONTAR.SE(INDIRECTO(""base_valid!$B$2:$B$6"")|M2)>0") and still no sucess... and if I use that same formula without the "" I get true in a cell

Comment: Also added a watch to cond1 and I get the following in "formula1" --> Formula1 : "=CONTAR.SE(INDIRECTO("base_valid!$B$2:$B$6")|L1048571)>0"

Comment: why in `"=CONTAR.SE(INDIRECTO(""base_valid!$B$2:$B$6"")|M2)>0")` do you use `|`?

Comment: because the separator I use is configured that way in Excel

Comment: @BigBen, edited this original answer to show also the option about using global scoped named ranges instead of INDIRECT :)